# magazine by magazine

Tags: meaning

Source: [Over 8,400 images from NASA's Moon missions are now on Flickr in high resolution](http://www.theverge.com/2015/10/2/9442951/nasa-apollo-moon-mission-photos-flickr)

Example:

> "These images were processed for inclusion on our websites, including adjusting color and brightness levels, and reducing the images in size to about 1000 dpi (dots per inch) for the high-resolution versions." Because there was so much demand for higher-resolution versions, Teague decided to reprocess the entire set and upload them to Flickr **magazine by magazine**.

What do they exactly mean by *magazine by magazine*? Magazines are weekly or monthly publications with articles and illustrations dedicated to a particular theme. Examples include Vibe, National Geographic etc. I don't think NASA stores their photo material in the form of a magazine.

Comment: If you search for *images* of slide magazines, you'll quickly figure out what they're referring to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long before it was a kind of print journal a *magazine* was a storehouse. The sense extended in various directions—an armory, where weapons were stored, a box or drum holding ammunition for a firearm, and eventually the lightproof canister in which photographic film was held before and after exposure.

The Apollo program of course predated digital photography, and the photographs in question were shot with Hasselblad cameras on rolls of light-sensitive film. Just two sentences before the passage you quote is this:

> "Around 2004, Johnson Space Center began re-scanning the original Apollo Hasseelblad camera film magazines, and Eric Jones and I began obtaining TIFF (uncompressed, high-resolution) versions of these new scans on DVD," Teague tells *The Planetary Society*.

Answer (score 4):

A magazine can also be a storage device for multiple units of something. So for instance, a magazine containing a number of bullets that you put in a gun.

So I interpret this as a "magazine" of slides, for instance, not a publication.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the "magazine" refers to the 70mm film magazines loaded onto the modified Hasselblad EL553 auto-winding medium format cameras. For instance, ["Magazine R"](http://airandspace.si.edu/collections/artifact.cfm?object=nasm_A19980007000) was the magazine used inside the lunar module of Apollo 11. The 70mm magazines could hold a considerably higher number of frames than the standard 120 (A12; 12 frames) and 220 (A24; 24 frames) film format backs. As far as I can determine, the original film from each of the magazines remains uncut in order to preserve frame order.